# Python FastAPI handle Multipart request

Tags: python, fastapi

and I need to build a Post Request API that handle multipart request. The body of post will contains as below

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
--abc12345--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"
AA123456789
--abc12345--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userdata"
Content-Type: application/json
{
....
}
--abc12345--
```

How can I using the fastAPI to extract the data? How to define the function parameters for the `@app.post`??

Thanksss...